# Using data flow with https on cloud foundry

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to deploy a data flow server on Cloud foundry and create a simple app.
Only https end point could be exposed. I cannot enable https using this :
http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-security-enabling-https
As ssl is managed by cf. How do I make data flow server using https?

I have this error:

```
dataflow:>app list
Command failed org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://dataflow-server.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/apps": Connect to dataflow-server.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io:80 [dataflow-server.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/54.201.89.124, dataflow-server.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/52.88.128.224] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to dataflow-server.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io:80 [dataflow-server.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/54.201.89.124, dataflow-server.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/52.88.128.224] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

as you already mentioned, you can not enable https at the container level inside cloudfoundry today. The traffic between the router and diego cell is not encrypted (unless you are using IPSEC).

So your dataflow server would not be configured with https, just deploy the server as it is. You should rely on your cloudfoundry install to have an open port at 443 on it's loadbalancer that forwards traffic to the router. Later CF incarnations support certificate placement at the router level.

Now, at the client (dataflow-shell) if you are using a valid certificate you don't need to do anything, but if you have a selfsigned certificate, you need to tell it to accept self-signed certificates, or skip validation all together.

Comment: ok, but the client is trying to reach http version of dataflow server endpoints which doesn't exist my 80 ports are not forwarded to 443. How can I make my client use 443 in this case. I am considering extending the shell, adding command line options, etc

Comment: What have you configured as the dataflow config server? Did you set it as https://dataflow-server.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io and it's trying to access the http endpoint?

Comment: Just to make sure, it was the https configuration at the server config? We tested here and setting as https, did make it call https endpoints

Comment: I do not have any dataflow config server, is this mandatory when deployed to CF ?

Comment: nope, I meant that `dataflow config server <https://>` was it the root cause of the issue? And what kind of authentication is not working at this context?